Task Queue: Release all messages at once to a single consumer when threshold is met
I'm looking for a task queue that supports pushing tasks into a queue and only releasing them to a single consumer at a time when a threshold number of messages is reached. When released to the consumer, the tasks must either be batched into a single task or delivered together (on the same execution). Does RabbitMQ or Redis happen to support this use case? If not if you can recommend an open-source alternative. Thank you.

It's supported as is by Valkey/Redis as is, but it's possible to build something like that pretty easily.
Can share the structure if you are interested. If so, also share the language you use.
